# Convert SQL Server stored procedure to Access Query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2003

I was using a SQL Server stored procedure for one of my calculations to display in a gridview in ASP.NET + VB code + access database web.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Report](
    @year int,
    @month int
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   declare @d smalldatetime
   declare @total int
   declare @dd smalldatetime

   set @d = CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@month AS varchar) + '-1' as smalldatetime)
   set @total = datediff(day, @d, dateadd(month, 1, @d))
   set @dd = CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(@month AS varchar) + '-'+CAST(@total AS varchar) as smalldatetime) 

   declare @R_perday decimal(18, 3)

   set @R_perday=
       case
          when @total = 31 then 2.471612903
          when @total = 30 then 2.554
          when @total = 29 then 2.642068966
          when @total = 28 then 2.736428571
    end

;WITH
    L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS i FROM L4)

select kamyno,Rank,Trade, Name,Pl,Appt,Cat, Days_Absent, Days_Present,
    @R_perday as R_perday,
    --case when Days_Absent=0 then @R_perday*Days_Present else @R_perday*Days_Absent end as C_Allce,
    @R_perday*Days_present as C_Allce,
    case
        when Days_Present>=20 then 38
        when Days_Present<=9 then 0
        when Days_Present>=10 then 19
    end as RC_Allce

from
(
    select kamyno, Rank,Trade, Name,Pl,Cat,Appt,CDPR, count(d) AS Days_Absent, @total-count(d) as Days_Present from
    (
        select * from
        (
            SELECT STAFF.kamyno, DATEADD(DAY, i-1, Rum.Out_dt) as d,Staff.Rank,Staff.Trade,Staff.Name,Staff.Pl,Staff.Appt,Staff.Cat,Staff.CDPR
            FROM Nums, Rum,
            STAFF
            where i <= 1+DATEDIFF(DAY, Rum.Out_dt, Rum.In_dt)
            AND STAFF.kamyno=Rum.kamyno
        ) a
        where month(d)=@month
        and year(d)=@year
    ) b
    group by kamyno,[Rank],Trade,Name,Pl,Cat,Appt,CDPR
    union
    select kamyno,[Rank],Trade, Name ,Pl,Cat,Appt,CDPR, 0 AS Days_Absent, @total as Days_Present
    from STAFF
    WHERE NOT kamyno IN (
        select kamyno from Rum
        where (month(Out_dt)=@month and year(Out_dt)=@year)
            OR (month(In_dt)=@month and year(In_dt)=@year)
            OR @d BETWEEN Out_dt AND In_dt
        )
AND STAFF.TORS <= @dd
) t

END
```

I want to use the same calculations in an access query. How can it be done? I have tried a lot and browsed and googled a lot, please help me.

I am giving my tables structure with some sample data here for reference.

MS-Access 2003 database web I have two tables; `STAFF` and `ABSENT`.

- In `STAFF` table, the details of people working in company is stored
- In `ABSENT` table, absence of the people is stored

I want to display the summary of absence of staff as per selected Month + Year (eg Aug 2013, Sep 2013) with a dropdownlist.

**STAFF**

```
PNO     Name
214     Raju
365     tamas
785     King
963     Sonu
```

**ABSENCE**

```
PNO    Name    Status       Out_dt              In_dt    
214    Raju    Leave         1 Sep 2013         12 Sep 2013
365    tamas   Out Duty      5 Sep 2013         10 Sep 2013
214    Raju    Leave        16 Sep 2013         18 sep 2013
```

I want this as output:

```
PNO    Name      Present   Absent
----------------------------------
214    Raju        15        15
365    tamas       24        06
785    King        30         0
963    Sonu        30         0
```

Comment: what are you having a hard time with? are you asking someone to recreate the SQL Server stored proc into an MS Access query?

Comment: Does it need to be just a query?  The logic in this case seems more suited to a VBA module hosted in Access.

Comment: May I ask why you are going backwards from SQL Server to MS Access? To convert this into MS Access querie(s) you need to push the variables back into the query to remove all the `declare`s and `set`s, change the 6 `WITH` CTE's into six queries (named L0,L1,L2,L3,L4,Nums) then finally create the last query, leaving @month and @year as parameters to the query. But seriously you are going backwards and you see this if you actually complete this requirement.

Comment: this project is a small application to manage staff of a institution. initially i designed it in sql express and it worked fine but there is a problem in installing attaching the database . people who are not familier with sql cannot be able ti install and configure it. but if this comes in access everything will be solved